# Using CLR to write files on the server

Tags: asp.net

IS it possible to use CRL procedure and C# to write files on the SQL Server file system? We have this server that is used for SQL but for other things as well and it would be usefull if we can create procedure that looks like this?

WriteData(string storedProcedureToExexute, string pathToSaveResults)

Are there any big considerations I need to take into account when working on this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for a CLR procedure to write the output to a file.

Something as simple as this should do the trick

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "YOUR_QUERY" queryout "YOUR_FILE" -T -c -t,'
```

Ofcourse you will need to have `xp_cmdshell` and `bcp` configured to do this.
Still better than having to write your own CLR procedure.

Are there any concerns. Both these commands are very powerful. `xp_cmdshell` will allow a user with access to them to run OS scripts directly on your server. You would want to very careful with which users you grant access to these commands.